# Configuration blocks in a Rails initializer don't work with local-path gems (?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, ruby-on-rails-5.1

In my Rails app Gemfile, I have `gem 'myfancygem', path: '/Users/matt/myfancygem'`

This works as you'd expect.

I then added a configuration block feature to the gem, a la https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block (and many others out there that are slight variants on this)

I created an initializer myfancygem.rb in my Rails app with the standard:

`Myfancygem.configure do |config|
  config.favorite_color = 'red'
end`

When running my local app (either in rails console, or rails server), that favorite_color does NOT get set. It remains at the default specified inside the gem (`nil`)

But if I push that gem to rubygems and load it normally (i.e. without the `path` bit in the Gemfile), the initializer config works as expected.

Just in case I was doing something nutty in my gem, I git cloned the latest copy of the ReactOnRails gem, which does pretty much the same configuration approach. Then I pointed my Gemfile at the local ReactOnRails via `path`. Guess what? SAME PROBLEM. The initializer I setup for my Rails app for ReactOnRails seems to be ignored. I even sprinkled `puts` statements into the initializers to prove they were getting executed and the configuration was being set, but then it would reset back to defaults right after `Rails.application.initialize!` in `environment.rb`

Ummm... what the heck?

Is this a known bug in Rails? Or Bundler? or something? Or is there some gotcha I'm missing? Or something I could have done wrong that I'm not realizing?

Comment: Especially in the beginning you should avoid forking and changing working gems.

Comment: Restarted server ?

Comment: To be clear, the point of the question was a strange behavior I'm seeing in a local Rails app using a local gem via the `path` parameter in the Gemfile. When building a new gem to work against a Rails app's API endpoints (that I also built), it's helpful to be able to hook the gem up via the app's Gemfile using `path` instead of constantly having to push it to a remote server. And that's when I discovered that my app-side configuration wasn't taking, but would work fine if not using the `path` in Gemfile. That's what is confusing me... tried restarting server, tried killing Spring, etc...

Comment: ok thats weird. Can you show your development.rb and Gemfile ?